# Access service worker skipWaiting from within App build with Webpack+Workbox

Tags: service-worker, workbox-webpack-plugin, aurelia

I have a PWA built with Aurelia and compiled with Webpack, using the Workbox Plugin that generates the `sw.js` service worker file.  I'm trying to make the "New version available" user notification so that the user can activate the new version when clicking on a link within the app.

I am successfully downloading and installing the new version in the background, and even detecting that a new version is ready.  However, when I try to call the `skipWaiting()` method to force refresh of the page with the new version, it fails, because apparently I don't have the right scope or object.

The main problem is probably that I can't edit the actual sw.js because it is automatically generated.  The examples all suggest the use of `self.skipWaiting();`, but I don't know how to access that object.

**webpack.config.js**

```
new WorkboxPlugin({
  globDirectory: './dist',
  globPatterns: ['**/*.{html,js,css,woff,woff2,ttf,svg,eot,jpg}'],
  swDest: './dist/sw.js',
  clientsClaim: true,
  skipWaiting: false, // because I want to notify the user and wait for response
}),
```

**index.ejs**

```
<script>
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js')
      .then(reg => {
        // make the registration available globally, for access within app
        window.myServiceWorkerReg = reg;
        // Check for update on loading the app (is this necessary?)
        return reg.update();
      })
      .catch(console.error);
  }
</script>
```

**app.js**

```
activate() {
  // listener for service worker update
  this.swReg = window.myServiceWorkerReg;
  console.warn('[app.js] ACTIVATE.', this.swReg);

  this.swReg.addEventListener('updatefound', () => {
    // updated service worker found in reg.installing!
    console.warn('[app.js] UPDATE FOUND.', this.swReg);

    const newWorker = this.swReg.installing;
    newWorker.addEventListener('statechange', () => {
      // has the service worker state changed?
      console.warn('[app.js]  STATE HAS CHANGED.', newWorker, newWorker.state);

      if (newWorker.state === 'installed') {
        // New service worker ready.

        // Notify user; callback for user request to load new app
        myUserMessage({ clickToActivate: () => {
          // reload fresh copy (do not cache)
          console.warn('[app.js] Post Action: skipWaiting.');
          // this.swReg.postMessage({ action: 'skipWaiting' });

          // THIS IS THE LINE THAT FAILS
          this.swReg.skipWaiting();
        }});
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Everything works fine except the last line (`this.swReg.skipWaiting();`).  Has anyone else used webpack+workbox plugin and gotten the skipWaiting to happen as a result of user interaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got it to work.  One problem was that I was using an older version of workbox-webpack-plugin.  The current version (4.2) includes a listener in the service worker that can trigger `self.skipWaiting()` when a message is posted to the worker like this:

```
newWorker.postMessage({ type: 'SKIP_WAITING' });
```

But you have to ensure that the config has `skipWaiting: false;` and that you are using the latest version.

These instructions are pretty good:

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-webpack-plugin

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/advanced-recipes#offer_a_page_reload_for_users

However, I tweaked things to work well between my App and the service worker instantiation in the index.ejs file.

**webpack.config.js**

```
new GenerateSW({
  globPatterns: ['dist/**/*.{html,js,css,woff,woff2,ttf,svg,eot,jpg}'],
  swDest: 'sw.js',
  clientsClaim: true,
  skipWaiting: false,
})),
```

**index.ejs**

```
<script>
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    // register the service worker
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js')
      .then(reg => {
        window.myWorkerReg = reg;
        // Check for update on loading the app (is this necessary?)
        return reg.update();
      })
      .catch(console.error);
    // The event listener that is fired when the service worker updates
    navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('controllerchange', function () {
      // when the service worker controller is changed, reload the page
      if (window.swRefreshing) return;
      window.location.reload();
      window.swRefreshing = true;
    });

  }
</script>
```

**app.js**

```
activate() {
  // listener for service worker update
  this.swReg = window.myWorkerReg;
  if (this.swReg) {
    // if there is already a new service worker ready to install, prompt user
    if (this.swReg.waiting) {
      this.promptUpdateServiceWorker(this.swReg.waiting);
    }
    // add listener to detect when a new service worker is downloaded
    this.swReg.addEventListener('updatefound', () => {
      // updated service worker is being installed
      const newWorker = this.swReg.installing;
      // add listener to detect when installation is finished
      newWorker.addEventListener('statechange', () => {
        if (newWorker.state === 'installed') {
          // New service worker ready to activate; prompt user
          this.promptUpdateServiceWorker(newWorker);
        }
      });
    });
  }
}

// listener for buildVersion
buildVersionChanged(buildVersion) {
  // through proprietary code, we've detected a new version could be downloaded now
  window.myWorkerReg.update();
}

// New service worker ready.  Show the notification
promptUpdateServiceWorker(newWorker) {
  // actual code for UI prompt will vary; this is pseudocode
  uiPrompt('New_version_ready').then((response) => {
    if (response.approved) {
      // reload fresh copy (do not cache)
      newWorker.postMessage({ type: 'SKIP_WAITING' });
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call it on the page (app.js). You call self.skipWaiting on the Service Worker script (service-worker.js).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerGlobalScope/skipWaiting

Comment: Very true.  That was one of the misunderstandings I had.  Fortunately, this particular package (workbox-webpack-plugin) creates a listener to allow you to trigger the skipWaiting by posting a message to the new worker that is waiting to be activated.  I added a complete description of my solution as the accepted answer to the question.